# google analytics showing wrong number of page views

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to stress test my google analytics system and I have sent around 100,000 request to the GA at the rate of about 3000/s . I have received 200 as the status code for successful ping to GA. All the request sent are exactly similar.

But when I see the real time dashboard the numbers are wrong and only shows about 1/3 the total requests sent. Has anybody observed similar behavior with GA?

Answer (score 1):

Do You know that a standart (free) version of GA has many restrictions? For example it has limited number of hits per second collect by it. It is normal behaviour to limit collected data if You make 3000 hits per second.

[As per documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/limits-quotas):

> ga.js:
>
> Each ga.js tracker object starts with 10 hits that are replenished at
>   a rate of 1 hit per second. Applies only to event type hits.
>
> analytics.js:
>
> Each analytics.js tracker object starts with 20 hits that are
>   replenished at a rate of 2 hit per second. Applies to All hits except
>   for ecommerce (item or transaction).
>
> Android SDK
>
> For each tracker instance on a device, each app instance starts with
>   60 hits that are replenished at a rate of 1 hit every 2 seconds.
>   Applies to All hits except for ecommerce (item or transaction).
>
> iOS SDK
>
> Each property starts with 60 hits that are replenished at a rate of 1
>   hit every 2 seconds. Applies to All hits except for ecommerce (item or
>   transaction).

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a source for your statement. These restrictions apply to Google Analytics Premium as well.